# Software to work with/view QuickTime Player panoramic images format

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, quicktime, mov

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS.

I have some panoramic views (mosaic images) made to be seen with QuickTime Player (from Apple), app we can use with WineHQ.

I'm talking about `.mov` files which has a lot of individual images joined  to give us a full panoramic view that we can see all around (360°) moving the screen pointer.

[Here's an example](http://underwatercolours.com/qtvr/reef.mov).

We can see other kinds of contents made to that specific format with VLC player, this specific panoramic view format cannot be enjoyed with VLC.

Of course, we can download and install QuickTime for Windows and use it through WineHQ, but I wonder...

Is there some native Linux software to view this kind of image?

Comment: Can you post a sample online?